# How do I fix this rewrite rule issue

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to change the URL in WordPress.

This is what I have as URL http://127.0.0.1/projectname/pagename/val1/val2/val3

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /projectname/
    RewriteRule pagename/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) pagename/?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /projectname/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I want my site to consider this as

http://127.0.0.1/projectname/pagename/?param1=val1&param2=val2&param3=val3

Comment: Not really php related, so maybe consider dropping that tag.

Comment: this is not PHP related, this related to .htaccess file, please use specific tags

Comment: Sounds like you want to undo the SEO Friendly Url settings. See `settings->permalinks` and undo it there

Comment: @RiggsFolly I want to keep the SEO friendly URL. I want to pass some data in URL. pagename is a page which I have created in wordpress admin and assigned it to a template. I have some custom logic in that template in which I need these variables also my SEO team would like to see them in URL for some reason but not as query params but as '/' separated URL

Comment: I got the fix for this. It was a typo in my case. Thanks everyone for the help

Comment: Either post the fix as an answer or delete the question, so we dont have a question without an answer left lying around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the solution in the WordPress way

```
add_action('init', 'custom_rule');

function custom_rule(){
    add_rewrite_tag('%param1%','([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_tag('%param2%','([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_tag('%param3%','([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_rule('^pagename/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?pagename=pagename&param1=$matches[1]&param2=$matches[2]&param3=$matches[3]','top');
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```